# How to write this ffmpeg command in python

Tags: python, ffmpeg

I have a streaming m3u8 links (one for video and one for audio)that I want to merge.

I've been doing this command line to do so:

```
ffmpeg  -i <audio> -i <video? -async 1 -c copy output.mp4
```

and it works just like I want, the problem is I am trying to do this for 100 different link, and I would like to write a code instead of doing this manually for each link. I know that this can be done in python, but I don't know how to translate an ffmpeg command to a python code.

Comment: Can you provide audio/video links examples?

Comment: `os.system("ffmpeg  -i <audio> -i <video> -async 1 -c copy output.mp4")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run code without catching displayed text

```
import os
os.system("ffmpeg -i <audio> -i <video> -async 1 -c copy output.mp4")
```

[subprocess](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html) has different methods

```
import subprocess

subprocess.run("ffmpeg -i <audio> -i <video> -async 1 -c copy output.mp4", shell=True)

subprocess.run( ["ffmpeg", "-i", "<audio>", "-i", "<video>", "-async", "1", "-c", "copy", "output.mp4"] )
```

Other methods can catch displayed text so you can check result.

Answer (score 0):

I used the code furas suggested and it worked:

```
import os
import pandas as pd 

D=pd.read_excel("links.xlsx");


for i in range(len(D.index)):
    video=D.iat[i,0]
    audio=D.iat[i,1]
    command='ffmpeg  -i '+audio+' -i '+video+' -async 1 -c copy '+str(i)+'.mp4'
    os.system(command)
```